# Deriving relationships among objects

Tags: java, algorithm, performance

Hi I am trying to devise an algorithm which given a set of Person Objects, gives me the relationship among them if there are any.

For Example:

Person A and B:

```
{ "name":"abc",
"address":"A main, B cross, C street, D state, E Country",
"age": 30,
"profession":"profession A"
}

{ "name":"xyz",
"address":"A main, B cross, C street, D state, E Country",
"age": 30,
"profession":"profession A"
}
```

Here i would say that both the person have the same attributes so my algorithm should identify them as aliases, The approach which i am following is given a new Person Object X i am trying to match the attributes of this person against everyone's attribute in the DB, This is seeming to be very slow, how can i improve this to be efficient?

Comment: show us what you have tried, maybe there is a obvious problem

Comment: What do you mean by "relationship among them"? Are you just trying to find aliases or even partial matches?

Comment: currently going with exact matches @JánHalaša

Comment: Questions asking for an off-site framework or library are off topic =[ sorry

Comment: @nhouser9 i am was just looking for the algorithm that is efficient at doing this, instead of doing a full table scan, i have removed the framework part

Answer (score 4):

Use a [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

```
Map<Person, List<Person>> personMap = new HashMap<>();
```

And override `hashCode()` and `equals()` methods for the `Person` class.

See - [Generating hashCode() for a custom class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36147943/generating-hashcode-for-a-custom-class).

#### Edit

If your data is huge, you can store index of `Person` array or ID or some unique identifer instead of `List<Person>`. Also you need to design a hash fast to generate.

#### Edit 2

Your `hashCode()` and `equals()` will look something like this -

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object other) {

    if (other == this) return true;
    if (!(other instanceof Person)) {
        return false;
    }

    Person person = (Person) other;

    return person.getName().equals(this.getName()) &&
            person.getAddr().equals(this.getAddr()) &&
            person.getAge() = this.getAge() &&
            person.getProfession().equals(this.getProfession());
}

//Idea from effective Java : Item 9
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int hash = 17;
    hash = 31 * hash + this.getName().hashCode();
    hash = 31 * hash + this.getAddr().hashCode();
    hash = 31 * hash + this.getAge();
    hash = 31 * hash + this.getProfession().hashCode();
    return hash;
}
```

Now if you can find any of the fields redundant to uniquely identify a person, you can skip the field in `hashCode()` and `equals()`.  Say, if every persons can be uniquely identified by his name and address, you won't need to consider `age` and `profession` in these methods resulting faster hashing.

Hope it helps!

Comment: This will be efficient when the data set is small, what if i have millions of records? will this method work ?

Comment: @kumarD check update.

Comment: actually i am looking for the efficient implementation of the equals method which you are talking about

Comment: @kumarD check the update

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to write a Comparator for Person classes, make List out of your Set and order the list. Then you can do it in one pass - just comparing the current and the next element. The Comparator would compare Persons by their attributes, so all aliases would get along each other in the sorted List.

Answer (score 0):

Assigning each attribute of person into a specific column in database table and creating index on those columns might run fast and does the job.